# Help with Canon CanoScan LiDE scanned PDF Documents

Tags: pdf, canon, scanner, ocr

I have just started working with Ubuntu for the last 10 days, with the intention to stop using Windows permanently. So far it has been awesome. I have replaced almost all my Microsoft applications with available Ubuntu apps and some help from Google Docs.

I am experiencing a problem with my Canon CanoScan LiDE 110 Scanner. When I use the scanner in Windows 7, and saved scanned pages of a book as PDF, I can open the PDF scanned page and copy text from it directly to paste at Google Docs or any LibreOffice document. I tried doing the same in Ubuntu using the *Simple Scan* app. I scanned the page as text in Simple Scan and saved it as a PDF. However in Ubuntu when I open the scanned PDF page, it opens OK, but I cannot copy the texts.

This is quite important for my workflow, as I am a medical physician and I need to study a lot of books.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tesseract OCR**

> Tesseract was one of top 3 OCR's in 1995.The development is now handled by google since 2006.It can scan images, convert to text and recognize 40 languages.

To install Tesseract

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

---

**Cuneiform**

> Cuneiform is another OCR system.It recognises 23 languages which include English, German, Russian, French etc.

To install Cuneiform

```
sudo apt-get install cuneiform
```

---

**Other apps that maybe useful**

- Ocradjvu
- Ocrad
- gocr
- ocrfeeder
- pdf studio 8 series

Comment: Hello Aditya,Hope you are doing well. Thanks a lot for your lead. I have started using Tesseract. Well, in another article i read that Gscan2pdf offers the option to select the OCR, and Tesseract is an option. I tried that ... and wow ... the text recognition was much better than the previous method I was using in Windows. Thanks a lot. One more step closer towards getting completely out of Windows. I tried to vote up your reply. But I do not have enough reputations. regards.

Comment: @learner SOme nice info.Google started developing **tesseract** probably because they wanted to scan thousands of books under there ongoing project.They must be using tesseract on there goobuntu computers.(guess what goobuntu stands for)